# Searchbar subview UITextField iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using a searchbar with the uitextField subview programatically. I get the image as below:

[image]

Here there is a dark color in the upper line. How can i avoid to get a plain thin line ?

i use this code:

```
searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height*10)/100, self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height*13)/100)];
searchbar.delegate=self;

for (searchBarSubview in [searchbar subviews]) {
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)] ) {
        @try {

            [[searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
            searchbar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            // ignore exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to roll your own search field with a UITextField and image

Comment: i am using the UITextField programmatically, but even then i cant overcome the dark line as i mentioned in the image.

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203472/designing-ios-searchbar) link, may help you

Comment: i just need to avoid the upper dark boarder line.